# Sum up values in Pig Tuple

Tags: hadoop, apache-pig

I have the following output of Pig tuple:

```
 dump g:
 ()
 (97)
 (245)
 (870)
 (480)

 describe g:
 g: {long}
```

I'm looking to sum up the total of the #'s above so I tried this:

```
 h = foreach g generate SUM($0);
```

I received this error:

```
 Please use an explicit cast.
```

I then tried to cast the value to (int) and still did not work.

The output I'm looking for is like this:

```
 1692
```

Here is the code leading up to:

```
 a = LOAD 'tellers' using TextLoader() AS line;
 # convert a to charrarry
 b = foreach a generate (chararray)line;  
 # run through my UDF to create tuples
 c = foreach b generate myudfs.TellerParser5(line);  # ({(20),(5),(5),(10)(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(5),(10),(10),(10)})....
 d = foreach c generate flatten(number); 
 e = group d by number; #{group: chararray,d: {(number: chararray)}}
 f = foreach e generate group, COUNT(d);  # f: {group: chararray,long}
 g = foreach f generate (long)$0 * $1;
```

Comment: post your whole script with input and expected output. It would be difficult to proceed from a dump result.

Comment: What's your question?

Comment: @kenorb I was to sum up those numbers

Comment: This is a total homework question!  We're probably in the same class!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would need to do something like this:

```
H = GROUP G ALL;
I = FOREACH H GENERATE SUM(G.$0);
```